# TightVNC resolution change crash

Tags: windows-7, crash, vnc

When the resolution of VNC server changes, the TightVNC client (on Windows 7) crashes.

What could be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Switched over to ThinVNC. Now it does not crash when I change the resolution.

Comment: Erm, but the download of ThinVNC does not seem to contain the client. Could you please explain where to find it?

Comment: Note that I don't own the server - and can't install the ThinVNC server there :(